# Get current (logged in) user in ASP.NET Core 6.0 Razor Pages

Tags: iis, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0

I've found solutions for retrieving the logged in user's information for [ASP.NET Core 6.0 **MVC**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72308247/getting-the-windows-user-name-in-asp-net-core-6-0) and **Blazor** but NOT for razor pages web apps. Am I supposed to create a controller and a startup.cs for my razor page web app OR is there another way?

Here's information on my set up...

- ASP.NET Core 6.0 web app (razor pages, not MVC)
- This site will be accessible from a parent site which the user will sign into using SSO so I don't need to create an identity solution; just need to retrieve the username, userid, roles they're members of & etc.
- Hosted in IIS
- Only users belonging to a certain role will be able to see the site; to be set in IIS

Comment: Did you learn Razor Pages? You need write code to the `.cshtml.cs` file. And it is the same with MVC from your shared link.

Comment: I know what code-behind files are. It just seems odd to create a controller (as mentioned  in the shared link) when I am not following an MVC pattern...

Comment: I tried adding IHttpContextAccessor (as noted in the shared link) to my IndexModel method and I get a "Dereference of a possibly null reference" error. This is so odd! Wish this was more clear. It's making migrating/upgrading to asp.net core 6 a pain :(

Comment: Hi @LeSteelBox, did you register the `IHttpContextAccessor`  in Program.cs?

Answer (score 0):

In Razor Pages, both of the PageModel and Razor page itself have a `User` property which gives you access to the currently logged in user:

*PageModel:*

```
public void OnGet()
{
    var currentUserName = User.Identity.Name;
}
```

*Razor Page*

```
<p>You are logged in a @User.Identity.Name</p>
```

Comment: Which assemblies should I use? System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal no longer seems to work with asp.net core 6.0; the app throws a "dereference of a possibly null reference error" when I use it. System.Web.Security no longer works either which I need to retrieve role information associated with a user.

This post mentions how the latter is no longer supported:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52475483/is-there-any-alternative-for-system-web-security-membershipuser-in-dotnetcore

Comment: @LeSteelBox 'dereference of a possibly null reference error' doesn't mean that it doesn't work. It is a warning that you might be referencing a null reference (which could result in a NullReferenceException). If you don't like those warnings, set `Nullable` to `disable` in the _.csproj_ file